# No PDF viewer installed error with LyX

Tags: errors, lyx, viewers, preview

Recently I reinstalled LyX under Windows 10. Even though I have installed foxit reader, I get a pop up message in preview that it says:

"No PDF viewer is installed. Please install a PDF viewer such as Adobe Reader".

I tried to reconfigure LyX after installing Nitro, but the problem remains.

Do I miss a specific setting in order to say to LyX to use Foxit Reader?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to overcome this problem by setting foxit reader as a default program for `pdf` files. For some reason, win10 by itself had set `microsoft edge` as the default program for `pdf` files.

In order to do so, do the followings: (This procedure works on win10. I assume that these steps are similar for win7 and win8)

control panel --> programs --> default programs --> associate a file type or protocol with a program

On the list, find .pdf format and associate it with your pdf reader.

After these steps, LyX's document preview works just fine

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer and explain *how* to set foxit reader as a default program for .pdf files. I know it might seem obvious to you, but it's always nice to add too many details than too few.

Comment: I would advise to install the free reader SumatraPDF, which is the best choice for TeX files: it doesn't lock the .pdf files when you recompile, allows for direct  and inverse search (don't know if this is important for LyX, but in a traditional TeX editor, it lets you go back and forth between a point in the .pdf and the corresponding line of code), is very small (< 3Mo) and ultra-fast).  

It has  a 64 bit version, if you're interested, [available here](http://www.zeniko.ch/#SumatraPDF).

Comment: TexWorks (that comes with the Windows LyX bundle) worked for me where Edge and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC did not.

Comment: @JosiahYoder TeXworks is a TeX editor and it comes with TeX distributions like Texlive and MiKTeX. It has nothing to do with LyX and definitely with windows

Comment: TexWorks includes a PDF reader

Comment: @JosiahYoder maybe... but as I said before, TeXworks has nothing to do with LyX. My problem was that I was unable to preview my LyX document, not that I wasn't able to compile my document

Comment: Sorry... to clarify ... an alternative to SumatraPDF is TexWorks's built-in PDF reader, which you can bind to LyX as recommended in this answer

Comment: @JosiahYoder since this discussion is on the comment line, you can put your advice as an answer :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if LyX can recognize Foxit Reader, but it will recognize the other readers if you've put them in the path.

I installed 2.2.0 (which is not really an upgrade, as it makes a separate install) on Windows 10 and had trouble getting LyX to recognize my Sumatra PDF installation.

Two things I had to do:

1. Add the path to the PDF viewer's binary, e.g., `C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF`:
   [image]
2. Do Tools > Reconfigure (so LyX will find the binary).
3. Set the File Handling > Viewer for `PDF (pdflatex)` to the reader (e.g., Sumatra in my case) that appears in the pull-down menu:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to install the free reader SumatraPDF, which is the best choice for TeX files: it doesn't lock the .pdf files when you recompile, allows for direct  and inverse search (don't know if this is important for LyX, but in a traditional TeX editor, it lets you go back and forth between a point in the .pdf and the corresponding line of code), is very small (< 3Mo) and ultra-fast).

It has  a 64 bit version, if you're interested, [available here](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/download-free-pdf-viewer.html).

Comment: Even with SumatraPDF installed, LyX isn't always finding it. Even with Sumatra's PATH in the LyX configuration options.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have Lyx installed, so I can't help. Just in case: did you try making SumatraPDF your default viewer? It lets you open with Acrobat Reader or PDFXchangeviewer from its File menu, anyway.